# Is there a faster way to know if it's a real triangle?

Tags: python

The following code is intended to return 0 if it's not possible to form a triangle with three given sides and return 1 if it *is* possible. Taking into account that it's not possible for a triangle to have an area of zero or less, first I calculated the semiperimeter of this hypothetical triangle and then return 1 if the result is greater than the greatest value in the given list. I did the previous because if the semiperimeter is less than the greatest value in the list, then when calculating the area with the Heron formula it would be an undefined root.

```
def isTriangle(aList):
    semiperimeter = (aList[0] + aList[1] + aList[2]) / 2
    if semiperimeter > max(aList):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

So I want to know if there is a faster way in Python to perform this (or at least with fewer lines of code).

Comment: How about `return sum(aList) / 2 > max(aList)`? and return a bool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if the sum of the two smaller sides is at least as large as the longest side:

```
def check(aList)
    return sum(aList) - max(aList) > max(aList)
```

With python 3.8+, you can avoid recomputing the maximum twice using a walrus operator:

```
def check(aList):
    return (m := max(aList)) < sum(aList) - m
```

Both solutions rely on numerical comparisons returning a big boolean. In python `bool` is a subclass of `int` that has only two possible singleton values: `True == 1` and `False == 0`. It's standard to return a `bool` rather than `0` or `1` for something like this. In fact, your original conditional could be replaced by

```
return semiperimeter > max(aList)
```

Or, absorbing the previous line into the return:

```
return sum(aList) / 2 > max(aList)
```

You could also write

```
return sum(aList) > 2 * max(aList)
```

This version avoids any type conversions, regardless if whether you pass in floats or integers (`/ 2` always results in a `float`).

Comment: Your answer and the others are what I was requesting, but I hadn't seen the walrus operator and know that I searched it I wonder if the second snippet of this answer you be instead:
```return (m := max(aList)) < sum(aList) - m``` ?

Answer (score -1):

You asked for shorter code. That one is possible to do as a oneliner.

```
def isTriangle(aList):
    return ((aList[0] + aList[1] + aList[2]) / 2) > max(aList) and 1 or 0
```

Exatly the same code, but just written shorter

Comment: Hmm.... Whoever gived minus to this answer, it would be nice to hear why. The quetion said "(or at least with less lines of code)". And I'd say that this does just it.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you could use `sum` and just get rid of the logical operators for a much cleaner solution

Comment: You are rigth, but that would change behaviour the code, if there isn't three elements in a list giving parameter. I'd return True of False instead of 1 or 0, but that would be change to behaviour as well.

Answer (score -1):

To determine if given 3 sides can form a valid triangle, I would suggest using [Triangle Inequality Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality). It roughly states that the sum of any two sides must always be equal or greater than the other side to be able to form a valid triangle.

Therefore, I would instead write something along this line. [Edited: initialization according to Avinash]

```
def isTriangle(aList):
    a,b,c = aList
    return (a + b >= c and a + c >= b and b + c >= a)
```

In case you really want to make it return `0` or `1` instead of `boolean` then you can use this return instead.

```
return 1 if a + b >= c and a + c >= b and b + c >= a else 0
```

Comment: This way also you can initialize: `a, b, c = aList`

Comment: That seems like a terribly inefficient way to do it, given access to `sum` and `max`. Also, OP's code is equivalent to the inequality.